# Secure Admin must be enabled to access the DAS remotely - Acess Glassfish Admin Console with Docker

Tags: docker, glassfish, dockerfile

I try to deploy my web app on glassfish which is on a docker container.
When I access to the Admin Console ( [IP]:4848 ), I can access to login page but there is this error message and I can't login:

> Secure Admin must be enabled to access the DAS remotely.

So I find on other post that I need to add these line in bin folder:

```
./asadmin start-domain
./asadmin change-admin-password
./asadmin enable-secure-admin
./asadmin stop-domain
./asadmin start-domain
```

But I can't do it because my glassfish instance is on a container.

For information, I run glassfish with:

```
sudo docker run -p 4848:4848 -p 8080:8080 -e GLASSFISH_PASS="password" -d glassfish
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this, but the best way is probably to copy [the method used in the Payara Server dockerfile](https://github.com/payara/docker-payaraserver-full/blob/master/Dockerfile). (Payara Server is derived from GlassFish and therefore the dockerfile is compatible with GlassFish too)

To summarise, this method creates 2 files: a `tmpfile` which contains the default (empty) password and the desired new password, and a `pwdfile` which contains just the newly changed file.

If the contents of the `tmpfile` are:

```
AS_ADMIN_PASSWORD=
AS_ADMIN_NEWPASSWORD=MyNewPassword
```

Then the contents of `pwdfile` should be:

```
AS_ADMIN_PASSWORD=MyNewPassword
```

to change the password using asadmin, the first file must be used with the `change-admin-password` command, and the second with all future commands.

In docker terms, this looks like this (taken directly from the dockerfile linked above):

```
ENV PAYARA_PATH /opt/payara41
ENV ADMIN_USER admin
ENV ADMIN_PASSWORD admin

# set credentials to admin/admin 

RUN echo 'AS_ADMIN_PASSWORD=\n\
AS_ADMIN_NEWPASSWORD='$ADMIN_PASSWORD'\n\
EOF\n'\
>> /opt/tmpfile

RUN echo 'AS_ADMIN_PASSWORD='$ADMIN_PASSWORD'\n\
EOF\n'\
>> /opt/pwdfile

RUN \
 $PAYARA_PATH/bin/asadmin start-domain && \
 $PAYARA_PATH/bin/asadmin --user $ADMIN_USER --passwordfile=/opt/tmpfile change-admin-password && \
 $PAYARA_PATH/bin/asadmin --user $ADMIN_USER --passwordfile=/opt/pwdfile enable-secure-admin && \
 $PAYARA_PATH/bin/asadmin restart-domain

# cleanup
RUN rm /opt/tmpfile
```

Comment: Damn, thanks !!!
For information, if someone have the same problem. You just need to take the file in @Mike's answer, et put it in a Dockerfile. Then, execute: 
sudo docker build -t myimage .  (do not forget the ".") and then, execute:
sudo docker run -it -p 4848:4848 -p 8080:8080 myimage  After that, you'll be able to change admin password.

Comment: That particular dockerfile is also available and maintained on Docker hub, so you can pull `payara/server-full` and you'll get the latest image. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

[~]# asadmin --port #your-admin-port# enable-secure-admin